# In Heroku, doing a POST using a SSL endpoint

Tags: ssl, heroku

I'm working an commerce with ActiveMerchant and the gateway requires to whitelist a list of IPs. Since the site it's hosted on Heroku and it's a cloud architecture every time you do `host app.herokyapp.com` will bring different IPs.

A regular POST through the app will be done from many different IPs every time.

```
heroku run 'curl -X POST -d "test=true" -k https://httpbin.org/post' --app=rebill
```

I been looking trough [SSL Endpoint](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl-endpoint), and looks like the endpoint always keep the same IPs. I been thinking that maybe theres a way to do the POST routing through the endpoint.

Any one knows if such as thing is possible or any other way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

There's a beta addon which was actually built to solve this problem, proximo: https://addons.heroku.com/proximo

Comment: That's great but seems to be running privately.